# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Book1.xls'

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/my_python/read1.py", line 3, in <module>
    book = open_workbook('Book1.xls',on_demand=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 449, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 941, in biff2_8_load
    f = open(filename, open_mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Book1.xls'
```

I am getting this error message in python while trying to open an excel sheet.....How can i solve this ?

Comment: Read the error message: "No such file or directory." That means that the file wasn't located where you thought it was located. Make sure the file is located in the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Either make sure Book1.xls is in "C:\my_python\", which is also where your script is, or use the full path to where Bool1.xls is located. For example:

```
book = open_workbook('C:\\Users\\Jeeva\\Documents\\Book1.xls',on_demand=True)
```